# $ionicLoading loader doesn't show when I installed my apk in my phone

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm working on a mobile app using ionic cordova everything is oky I used $ionicLoading loader to show message to user when I load some data from the web service when I test my app on the web browser it's work right and I see the message from $ionicLoading but when I build my android apk and installed it on my phone it's work but I can't see the message $ionicLoading I don't know what is the problem can any one have an idea about that Thanks

This my code :

```
appMain.controller('HomeController', ['$scope','authService','$ionicLoading','$location','$ionicModal','$ionicPopup','$ionicSideMenuDelegate','$http','$routeParams','$cordovaGeolocation', function ($scope,authService,$ionicLoading,$location,$ionicModal,$ionicPopup,$ionicSideMenuDelegate,$http,$routeParams,$cordovaGeolocation, $timeout) {

    $scope.getQuestionsOfTheme=function(){
        $scope.show();
        $http.get(authService.getServiceBase()+"api/Questionnaire/getQuestionOfTheme?code="+$routeParams.code+"")
               .success(function(data){
                $scope.questions=data; 
                $scope.totalQuestion=$scope.questions.length;
                $scope.hide();
                $scope.nextQuestion();            
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data, status, headers, config);
                 $scope.hide();
            });

    }
    $scope.show = function() {
        $ionicLoading.show({
          template: 'Chargement...'

        }).then(function(){

        });
      };
      $scope.hide = function(){
        $ionicLoading.hide().then(function(){

        });
      };
}]);
```

Comment: Can you share your code snippet?

Comment: Yes I add the code

Comment: try removing '.then' from the $ionicloading.show and $ionicloading.hide

Comment: Maybe you get the response to fast and you can't see it. Try hiding the `$ionicLoading` after the view is rendered. Use `$ionicView.loaded`, you can find more info [http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/#usage](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/#usage).